# Jasper Report: Main Report is Blank when one of the Sub Report has no data

Tags: jasper-reports

I've four sub Reports in a main Report. Getting Blank page when one of my sub Report has no data. But i want rest of the Sub Report's data to be displayed in main Report.

is there any option to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see something being generated even when there is no data in the supplied data source, then you should try set the whenNoDataType property to "AllSectionsNoDetail". See https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/empty-report-problem